# Simplification of a function involving squares

Tags: real-analysis

Simple one I hope... I have a function of the form
$$
q(x) := q(x;a,b) = \frac{x^2}{\left(a^2 x^2 + b^2x^2\right)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}
$$
where $a,b,x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m>0$ is an integer.

Is it possible, or even correct, to assert
$$
q(x) = \frac{1}{|x|^{m-1} \left(a^2+b^2\right)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}?
$$
Or is it still admissible that $q(x)<0$ for $x<0$ with $m$ even?  Are there any conditions that must be met for the correct result to hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a,b,x$ cannot all be equal to $0$ simultaneously.

That said, $$q(x) = \frac{x^2}{(a^2 x^2 + b^2x^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}=\frac{x^2}{[x^2(a^2  + b^2)]^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}=\frac{x^2}{(x^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}(a^2  + b^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}=\\\frac{(x^2)^{{1-\frac{m+1}{2}}}}{(a^2  + b^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}=\frac{(x^2)^{{\frac{2-m+1}{2}}}}{(a^2  + b^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}=\\\frac{(x^2)^{{\frac{1-m}{2}}}}{(a^2  + b^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}=\frac{|x|^{1-m}}{(a^2  + b^2)^{\frac{m+1}{2}}}>0$$

Comment: I'm not sure this is conclusive in the case, for example $x=-1$ and $m=2$.

Comment: @RickyBoy For whatever reason I thought $x>0$. Will edit last step where ${(x^2)^{{\frac{1-m}{2}}}}=|x|^{1-m}$.

Comment: OK, understood, thanks for reviewing.  In which case it seems you support the assertion in my question.  So, per your claim that $(x^2)^{\frac{1-m}{2}} = |x|^{1-m}$, is it just as simple as that?  Or is this just a very precise and accurate way of expressing a fact?

Comment: Put another way: Is it true that $q(x)>0 \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ provided $a$ and $b$ are not zero simultaneously with $x=0$?

Comment: @RickyBoy Yes on both accounts as far as I can see.